# Performance gets slower during collect signature when volume is high

Tags: corda

I tried to create ~100 LinearStates. Its in a flow that only contains a `N for-each loop` that subFlow another `IssueFlow` which issues one state per tx.
This is on  Corda 3.0, Azure Cloud with `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2673 v3 @ 2.40GHz 4GB RAM`

The linear state consists of

1. Borrower
2. Lender
3. Regulator

During CollectSignature, in the first 40~50 states, it takes around 3~4 seconds for EACH participant to respond. But as it goes on, it can take up to 14+ seconds for the initiator to receive the response.  Why is there a degradation of performance as the volume increases?

The benchmark below for total duration

1. 10 States ~2.5 mins
2. 50 States ~30 mins
3. 100 States ~105 mins

The example log here, you can see it takes up to 16 seconds for the initiator to process the participants response in collect signature.

**Start time with LENDER  :** 2018-06-29T11:07:56,356Z

**END time with LENDER :**  2018-06-29T11:08:12,669Z

```
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:07:56,356Z [Node thread-1] flow.[55168e42-bff4-4d75-94ba-304d63f1a58e].initiateSession - Initiating flow session with party OU=LENDER, O=LENDER, L=London, C=UK. Session id for tracing purposes is SessionId(toLong=-1958500197946881585). {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:02,251Z [Thread-179 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.artemisToCordaMessage - Received message from: p2p.inbound.DjcvsLH1DL2QVRWbG7ucYLKtmraM8ch2RhCL5TEMJxWCdW user: OU=LENDER, O=LENDER, L=London, C=UK topic: platform.session uuid: 50a1b9aa-4c15-4c8e-a744-8df109103837 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=BORROWER, O=BORROWER, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2f62be30-746e-41c5-9939-719d0653c038, invocation_timestamp=2018-06-29T10:36:49.307Z, session_id=9d602c15-c391-434c-9f6c-c44f662e261c, session_timestamp=2018-06-29T06:55:33.044Z}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:05,281Z [Thread-179 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.artemisToCordaMessage - Received message from: p2p.inbound.DjcvsLH1DL2QVRWbG7ucYLKtmraM8ch2RhCL5TEMJxWCdW user: OU=LENDER, O=LENDER, L=London, C=UK topic: platform.session uuid: ff4dd716-caaf-43e5-a462-f64844266659 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=BORROWER, O=BORROWER, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2f62be30-746e-41c5-9939-719d0653c038, invocation_timestamp=2018-06-29T10:36:49.307Z, session_id=9d602c15-c391-434c-9f6c-c44f662e261c, session_timestamp=2018-06-29T06:55:33.044Z}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:12,669Z [Thread-177 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.artemisToCordaMessage - Received message from: p2p.inbound.DjcvsLH1DL2QVRWbG7ucYLKtmraM8ch2RhCL5TEMJxWCdW user: OU=LENDER, O=LENDER, L=London, C=UK topic: platform.session uuid: b2ff1807-b9ef-49dd-aabb-d69253ce5f28 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=BORROWER, O=BORROWER, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2622b6f6-82f7-417b-a1ea-3c2207bb1a03, invocation_timestamp=2018-06-29T11:04:40.745Z, session_id=9d602c15-c391-434c-9f6c-c44f662e261c, session_timestamp=2018-06-29T06:55:33.044Z}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:15,193Z [Node thread-1] flow.[55168e42-bff4-4d75-94ba-304d63f1a58e].initiateSession - Initiating flow session with party OU=REGULATOR, O=REGULATOR, L=London, C=UK. Session id for tracing purposes is SessionId(toLong=-8884253824391485917). {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:16,810Z [Thread-179 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.artemisToCordaMessage - Received message from: p2p.inbound.DjcvsLH1DL2QVRWbG7ucYLKtmraM8ch2RhCL5TEMJxWCdW user: OU=REGULATOR, O=REGULATOR, L=London, C=UK topic: platform.session uuid: fd68ae1d-fa64-4a90-aeb5-c987f73836c3 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=BORROWER, O=BORROWER, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2f62be30-746e-41c5-9939-719d0653c038, invocation_timestamp=2018-06-29T10:36:49.307Z, session_id=9d602c15-c391-434c-9f6c-c44f662e261c, session_timestamp=2018-06-29T06:55:33.044Z}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:19,913Z [Thread-179 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.artemisToCordaMessage - Received message from: p2p.inbound.DjcvsLH1DL2QVRWbG7ucYLKtmraM8ch2RhCL5TEMJxWCdW user: OU=REGULATOR, O=REGULATOR, L=London, C=UK topic: platform.session uuid: 3cadd008-4cf4-4e89-bcaf-92200c1f9c08 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=BORROWER, O=BORROWER, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2f62be30-746e-41c5-9939-719d0653c038, invocation_timestamp=2018-06-29T10:36:49.307Z, session_id=9d602c15-c391-434c-9f6c-c44f662e261c, session_timestamp=2018-06-29T06:55:33.044Z}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:24,468Z [Thread-177 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.artemisToCordaMessage - Received message from: p2p.inbound.DjcvsLH1DL2QVRWbG7ucYLKtmraM8ch2RhCL5TEMJxWCdW user: OU=REGULATOR, O=REGULATOR, L=London, C=UK topic: platform.session uuid: 5295d816-0605-42f4-b53a-d34761ed2b03 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=BORROWER, O=BORROWER, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2622b6f6-82f7-417b-a1ea-3c2207bb1a03, invocation_timestamp=2018-06-29T11:04:40.745Z, session_id=9d602c15-c391-434c-9f6c-c44f662e261c, session_timestamp=2018-06-29T06:55:33.044Z}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:27,325Z [Node thread-1] flow.[55168e42-bff4-4d75-94ba-304d63f1a58e].initiateSession - Initiating flow session with party O=NetworkMapAndNotary, L=London, C=UK. Session id for tracing purposes is SessionId(toLong=4774527641719127102). {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:29,355Z [Thread-179 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.artemisToCordaMessage - Received message from: p2p.inbound.DjcvsLH1DL2QVRWbG7ucYLKtmraM8ch2RhCL5TEMJxWCdW user: O=NetworkMapAndNotary, L=London, C=UK topic: platform.session uuid: 7a149d3e-cea8-46e4-8d05-09bb43d6d18b {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=BORROWER, O=BORROWER, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2f62be30-746e-41c5-9939-719d0653c038, invocation_timestamp=2018-06-29T10:36:49.307Z, session_id=9d602c15-c391-434c-9f6c-c44f662e261c, session_timestamp=2018-06-29T06:55:33.044Z}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:32,224Z [Thread-179 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.artemisToCordaMessage - Received message from: p2p.inbound.DjcvsLH1DL2QVRWbG7ucYLKtmraM8ch2RhCL5TEMJxWCdW user: O=NetworkMapAndNotary, L=London, C=UK topic: platform.session uuid: eb1b0a8c-a759-47aa-96f5-57e4a3ec27a4 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=BORROWER, O=BORROWER, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2f62be30-746e-41c5-9939-719d0653c038, invocation_timestamp=2018-06-29T10:36:49.307Z, session_id=9d602c15-c391-434c-9f6c-c44f662e261c, session_timestamp=2018-06-29T06:55:33.044Z}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:35,331Z [Thread-179 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.artemisToCordaMessage - Received message from: p2p.inbound.DjcvsLH1DL2QVRWbG7ucYLKtmraM8ch2RhCL5TEMJxWCdW user: O=NetworkMapAndNotary, L=London, C=UK topic: platform.session uuid: f25ea565-23b0-4dd6-bb2d-38fe9c5f0529 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=BORROWER, O=BORROWER, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2f62be30-746e-41c5-9939-719d0653c038, invocation_timestamp=2018-06-29T10:36:49.307Z, session_id=9d602c15-c391-434c-9f6c-c44f662e261c, session_timestamp=2018-06-29T06:55:33.044Z}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:35,339Z [Node thread-1] vault.NodeVaultService._queryBy - Vault Query for contract type: interface net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState, criteria: VaultQueryCriteria(status=UNCONSUMED, contractStateTypes=null, stateRefs=[AA7F52DA4BC71835C46FCFBA4542372DC261F9885BA8B2614A9C111D24A5091A(0), 19CCA05079E7F5F34EB91C50F1EA7D7D7599662BB55A57B65E91F6D7BFE63602(1)], notary=null, softLockingCondition=null, timeCondition=null), pagination: PageSpecification(pageNumber=-1, pageSize=200), sorting: Sort(columns=[]) {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:35,382Z [Node thread-1] flow.[55168e42-bff4-4d75-94ba-304d63f1a58e].initiateSession - Initiating flow session with party OU=LENDER, O=LENDER, L=London, C=UK. Session id for tracing purposes is SessionId(toLong=-607600376681252697). {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:36,936Z [Thread-179 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.artemisToCordaMessage - Received message from: p2p.inbound.DjcvsLH1DL2QVRWbG7ucYLKtmraM8ch2RhCL5TEMJxWCdW user: OU=LENDER, O=LENDER, L=London, C=UK topic: platform.session uuid: 64b87ae0-e744-4b56-aff6-25d4a2ef7c34 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=BORROWER, O=BORROWER, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2f62be30-746e-41c5-9939-719d0653c038, invocation_timestamp=2018-06-29T10:36:49.307Z, session_id=9d602c15-c391-434c-9f6c-c44f662e261c, session_timestamp=2018-06-29T06:55:33.044Z}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:39,844Z [Thread-179 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.artemisToCordaMessage - Received message from: p2p.inbound.DjcvsLH1DL2QVRWbG7ucYLKtmraM8ch2RhCL5TEMJxWCdW user: OU=LENDER, O=LENDER, L=London, C=UK topic: platform.session uuid: 8a5520a9-fafa-48b0-82cb-a951b60f6a4c {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=BORROWER, O=BORROWER, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2f62be30-746e-41c5-9939-719d0653c038, invocation_timestamp=2018-06-29T10:36:49.307Z, session_id=9d602c15-c391-434c-9f6c-c44f662e261c, session_timestamp=2018-06-29T06:55:33.044Z}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:42,980Z [Thread-179 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.artemisToCordaMessage - Received message from: p2p.inbound.DjcvsLH1DL2QVRWbG7ucYLKtmraM8ch2RhCL5TEMJxWCdW user: OU=LENDER, O=LENDER, L=London, C=UK topic: platform.session uuid: 0760d9e0-9f6f-47e7-8875-0a89a805c8e3 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=BORROWER, O=BORROWER, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2f62be30-746e-41c5-9939-719d0653c038, invocation_timestamp=2018-06-29T10:36:49.307Z, session_id=9d602c15-c391-434c-9f6c-c44f662e261c, session_timestamp=2018-06-29T06:55:33.044Z}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:42,981Z [Node thread-1] flow.[55168e42-bff4-4d75-94ba-304d63f1a58e].initiateSession - Initiating flow session with party OU=REGULATOR, O=REGULATOR, L=London, C=UK. Session id for tracing purposes is SessionId(toLong=4404924816331214061). {}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:46,011Z [Thread-179 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.artemisToCordaMessage - Received message from: p2p.inbound.DjcvsLH1DL2QVRWbG7ucYLKtmraM8ch2RhCL5TEMJxWCdW user: OU=REGULATOR, O=REGULATOR, L=London, C=UK topic: platform.session uuid: 2ff5f6ee-59af-4e96-b9e5-b081cc59e5b7 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=BORROWER, O=BORROWER, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2f62be30-746e-41c5-9939-719d0653c038, invocation_timestamp=2018-06-29T10:36:49.307Z, session_id=9d602c15-c391-434c-9f6c-c44f662e261c, session_timestamp=2018-06-29T06:55:33.044Z}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:47,435Z [Thread-179 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.artemisToCordaMessage - Received message from: p2p.inbound.DjcvsLH1DL2QVRWbG7ucYLKtmraM8ch2RhCL5TEMJxWCdW user: OU=REGULATOR, O=REGULATOR, L=London, C=UK topic: platform.session uuid: 24e23ab9-3a38-4b26-a1dc-b113332bfa20 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=BORROWER, O=BORROWER, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2f62be30-746e-41c5-9939-719d0653c038, invocation_timestamp=2018-06-29T10:36:49.307Z, session_id=9d602c15-c391-434c-9f6c-c44f662e261c, session_timestamp=2018-06-29T06:55:33.044Z}
[INFO ] 2018-06-29T11:08:50,487Z [Thread-179 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.artemisToCordaMessage - Received message from: p2p.inbound.DjcvsLH1DL2QVRWbG7ucYLKtmraM8ch2RhCL5TEMJxWCdW user: OU=REGULATOR, O=REGULATOR, L=London, C=UK topic: platform.session uuid: fbf75fab-5250-4a80-a3e6-96cf30c66082 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=OU=BORROWER, O=BORROWER, L=London, C=UK, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=2f62be30-746e-41c5-9939-719d0653c038, invocation_timestamp=2018-06-29T10:36:49.307Z, session_id=9d602c15-c391-434c-9f6c-c44f662e261c, session_timestamp=2018-06-29T06:55:33.044Z}
```

Comment: Can you add the Corda version please?

Comment: Also, how are you creating these states? Are you creating one transaction per flow, with one state per transaction?

Comment: Added Corda version. Its in a flow that only contains a for-each loop that subFlow another IssueFlow which issues one state per tx.

Answer (score 0):

In Corda, nodes create a checkpoint each time they send or receive information as part of a flow (these checkpoints are then automatically removed once they're obsolete). The time it takes to create this checkpoint depends partly on the number of objects to be serialised.

In this case, each iteration of the `for` loop was adding a new object to a list. As this list grew, checkpointing took longer and longer.

Comment: Is there any housekeeping of the node checkpoint table? does it push/pop itself or is manual intervention required to manager the DB table?

Comment: The checkpoints are automatically removed once they're obsolete.

Comment: Just for clarification and an update, the issue is not related to adding a new object to a new list. So far the findings is that having one flow creating multiple transactions in same flow uuid will cause more and more objects being serialised and cause exponential slowness.